# Solidworks static simulation having issues

Tags: mechanical-engineering, statics, cad, solidworks, autocad

I've got everything set. Material is aluminum alloy 6061. I've set the component contacts to no penetration. I have a contact set where both blocks meet and keep getting the same error. The bottom part is fixed. The head coming out has a no penetration contact with the top block. The only thing that works is by making it globally binded but I'm pretty sure that they are meant to not be binded[image: objects]

Comment: What prevents the smaller part sliding around in that slot with no constraints?

Comment: It should be able to slide around. Its basically a block, a thin cylinder and a thick cylinder so it should be able to move around the hole made by the top block

Comment: But in the simulation you have set up it can slide (and possibly rotate/spin?) with *zero resistance* which makes the simulation unstable. Try adding a rotational constraint and a weak force (much lower than the applied force elsewhere) to bias it towards one end of the slot or the other. Do you have friction included at the interface also?

Comment: Added a roller in the back and some friction. Not ideal but it worked. Thank you.

Comment: I guess I should have written an answer instead of a comment, then ;)